# SSLException while testing spring boot rest endpoint using JMeter

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, sslexception

I am trying to do load testing with JMeter for a spring boot application running locally on port 8080.
Request configured is a GET request, and protocol is https. I get following error message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:184)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
```

Any input on it would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are most probably using https to hit the server while you should use http as port 8080 is usually for http.

Otherwise change port to 8443 for https

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where to make this change?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you cross-check the port number on JMeter?

make sure that the same port is defined in JMeter as well.

```
https://localhost/application/sub/url
```

For the above URL, the port number is 443 which is the default port for https

```
https://localhost:8080/application/sub/url
```

Whereas the above URL uses 8080 for communication.

Please make sure the correct port has been specified.

Additionally, also note that that JMeter itself doesn't allow unsigned certificates. Make sure the certificates are properly signed via Certificating Authority.