# Getting Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException while calling external API

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am calling an external Rest endpoint in my application. But I am getting the following error:

```
 The response body does not contain an access token
 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for 
 "https://example.com/api/auth": Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message; nested exception is 
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
```

In this context, I found an article as follows:

[Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

But, I did not find this useful, as I am talking to an HTTPS server with port number 443.

Can this happen because of the whitelisting, I mean the HTTPS server endpoint, that I am connecting to, is not whitelisted yet?

Comment: what if you `curl -v https://example.com/api/auth` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced the exception as listed by you, although it was in a different scenario. I see there isn't an answer to the question yet, so I'm sharing my experience of how I fixed it, based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63400245/9602527) that helped me realise the issue was somehow related to `https` vs `http`. This answer might also be useful to someone who's trying to achieve what I tried below.

I experienced this with Apache HttpClient when trying to connect to a secure endpoint whilst routing via a proxy.

I had implemented a custom `RoutePlanner` by extending `DefaultRoutePlanner` and implemented the `determineProxy` method as follows:

```
@Override
protected HttpHost determineProxy(final HttpHost target, final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) {
    return new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, target.getScheme());
}
```

The problem was that the target's scheme was `https`. By dropping the scheme argument the `HttpHost` will automatically set it to just `http`.

Here is the working code:

```
@Override
protected HttpHost determineProxy(final HttpHost target, final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) {
    return new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
}
```

In other words, in order to reach the `https` endpoint I needed to route via the proxy, whose host is just `http`.

Comment: This helped me solve a similar problem with RedHat's Resteasy client. I configured it to use a proxy for HTTPS, but I needed to configure it for HTTP too otherwise I got this same error.